# Select time range from zoo time series

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I have the following time series:

```
library (zoo)
ts1 <- "f,c
    1,19/11/2014 12:00,0.01
    2,19/11/2014 13:00,0.01
    3,20/11/2014 15:00,0.01
    4,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
    5,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
    6,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
    7,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
    8,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03
    9,21/11/2014 16:00,0.01
    10,21/11/2014 17:00,0.01"

z <- read.zoo(text = ts1, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", sep = ",")
```

I would like to create a new zoo - `z1` that will be subset of z that will include the time range `20/11/2014 15:00` till `20/11/2014 23:00`. It will include the following:

```
    3,20/11/2014 15:00,0.01
    4,20/11/2014 16:00,0.01
    5,20/11/2014 17:00,0.01  
    6,20/11/2014 19:00,0.01  
    7,20/11/2014 22:00,0.20  
    8,20/11/2014 23:00,0.03
```

Comment: Check out ?zoo::window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lubridate)
window(z, start = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 15:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"), 
   end = parse_date_time("20/11/2014 23:00", orders = "%d-%m-%Y H!:M!"))
```

Comment: Note that this can be shortened to `window(z, start = "2014-11-20 15:00:00", end = "2014-11-20 23:00:00")` which does not need lubridate.